# How to use tabstrip in VB6?

Tags: tabs, vb6

I searched about tabs in VB6 over and over, but I couldn't find anyway. How I can replace buttons and other thing in which tab?

```
Private Sub TabStrip1_Click()
```

Comment: You don't. You have to manually show/hide the controls depending on current tab being clicked. Best approach is to put all controls belonging to tab in a PictureBox and show/hide this container. Even better -- make a control array of PictureBox'es for all the tabs you plan on impl.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the answer. All objects in each tab must be in one frame and each frame must be for a special tab.

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_use_tabstrip.html

Answer (score -1):

1. Start a new project
2. Add a new form from availables templates: choose the **Options window** template

Now you have a form **frmOptions** which contains a TabStrip named **tbsOptions**, complete of code to manage the tabs using the Click event.